# Point Cloud Library Error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, point-cloud-library

I am trying to run a simple code of Point Cloud library, first import include and lib directories to project properties and also add linker. but when I build my project compiler show me many errors as see on the below image? 
what's the problem
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem, correct libraries and include path in properties.